# TypeError: a float is required in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, math, typeerror

I have a Python3 script as follows:

```
import math

Value_1 = float(input("what's the X1 value?")), float(input("what's the X2 value?"))

Value_2 = float(input("what's the Y1 value?")), float(input("what's the Y2 value?"))

equation =(math.sqrt(math.sqrt(Value_1)+ math.sqrt(Value_2)))

print (equation)
```

with this output

> what's the X1 value?3.0
>
> what's the X2 value?12.0
>
> what's the Y1 value?10.0
>
> what's the Y2 value?110.0

**Then the program return this error:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-cc8d8b28ff67> in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 equation = float(math.sqrt(math.sqrt(Value_1)+ math.sqrt(Value_2)))
      8 
      9 print (equation)

TypeError: a float is required
```

I have tried to use all tips for other questions but error persist. Any tips?

Comment: `Value_1` and `Value_2` are tuples containing two numbers. What did you expect to happen when you call `sqrt` on a tuple?

Answer (score 1):

no one cares about my question but I figure out it by myself. Here we go:

```
import math

x1 = float(input("what's the X1 value?"))

x2 = float (input("what's the X2 value?"))

print (x2 - x1)

xdiff = abs (x2 - x1)

print (xdiff)

y1 = float(input("what's the y1 value?"))

y2 = float (input("what's the y2 value?"))

ydiff = abs(y2 - y1)
print (ydiff)


math.sqrt(math.pow(xdiff,2) + math.pow(ydiff,2))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Welcome to SO monte negromf. Thank you for posting an answer to you own question. It is very helpful for other readers/ users. As for your question not receiving much traffic, you have some options to influence that. If you did not receive an answer after some days, try editing your question to provide additional information or clarify the problem. The edit will make it bump up in the "new questions" feed again. If you take a look at the edits Console made to your question and answer, they made the code much easier to read. This can greatly increase your chance of answers. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions and tips. This is my very fist code, once I am a biomedical scientist

Answer (score 1):

#### What is the problem?

By assigning to inputs to `Value_1`, separated by a comma, you are defining a tuple. As a short example for this:

```
In [1]: tup = 42, 23

In [2]: type(tup)
Out[2]: tuple
```

However, the `math.sqrt` function requires a float value as input, not a tuple.

#### How to solve this

You can use tuple unpacking to keep the structure of your original post intact:

```
import math

# read in x and y value of the first point and store them in a tuple
point_1 = float(input("What is the x value of point 1? ")), float(input("What is the y value of point 1? "))
# read in x and y value of the second point and store them in a tuple
point_2 = float(input("What is the x value of point 2? ")), float(input("What is the y value of point 2? "))

# This is where the tuple unpacking happens.
# After this you have the x and y values
# of the points in their respective variables.
p1_x, p1_y = point_1
p2_x, p2_y = point_2

# At this point you can use point_1 when you need both x and y value of
# of the first point. If you need only the x or y value you can use the
# unpacked coordinates saved in p1_x and p1_y respectively.

x_diff = abs(p1_x - p2_x)
y_diff = abs(p1_y - p2_y)

distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(x_diff, 2) + math.pow(y_diff, 2))
print("Distance of {} and {} is {}".format(point_1, point_2, distance))
```

As you can see above it can be helpful to save the information for the point as a tuple first and then use the unpacked coordinates at at a different point.

I hope this sheds some light on what happened.

Comment: that´s  amazing and very didactic! Thank you very much for it, next time i will try to follow your model